# Как добавить в footer социальные иконки bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Вот моя картинка с социальными иконками. Мне необходимо добавить их, используя `bootstrap / css`.

Как спроектировать  разделение иконок используя `bootstrap` или `css`?
 Здесь мой код для  `footer`.

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="container text-left">
            <small style="color:grey" class="copyright">Copyright &copy 2015 SVAPP Private Limited.All Rights Reserved.</small>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-skype pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter pull-right">  </small></a>
            <a href="#"><small style="color:grey" class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook pull-right">  </small></a>
        </div><!--End container-->
    </footer><!--End footer 2-->
```

Картинка [здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVKWF.jpg)

Перевод вопроса: [How to add the footer with social icons in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33517524/7394871) @Prajwal K M

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517524/how-to-add-the-footer-with-social-icons-in-bootstrap/33518069#33518069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот одно из решений, как вы можете создать это с помощью **`Bootstrap`** и [**Font awesome icons**](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

[У  глифов](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) `Bootstrap` нет социальных иконок, поэтому вы можете включить некоторые другие `icons font`.

```css
.footer {
  background: #061D25;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.footer a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #70726F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.footer a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #70726F;
}
.footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Вы также можете создать это без `framework Bootstrap`, и `css` будет почти таким же, вам просто нужно включить ещё `icons font`.

```css
footer {
  background: #061D25;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
footer a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #70726F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
footer a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #70726F;
}
footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
</footer>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33518069/7394871)