# Изменить цвет svg path

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая разноцветная svg с 4 path, у каждого path свой цвет [скрин](http://joxi.ru/DrlR94EHvdgYP2) Нужно на ховер задать всем path одинаковый цвет, к примеру белый.

Comment: Как вариант, можно менять background-image: url(путь к файлу), при ховере сделать белой

Comment: да, так можно, еще можно накладывать сверху блок с белой иконкой, в принципе одно и тоже)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [изменение цвета svg при наведении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701557/%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-svg-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы было видно белый цвет, я сделал фон самого svg серым, в общем  смотрите.

```html
<svg width="120px" height="120px" version="1.1" viewBox="9 164 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  style="background: #ccc;">
 <defs>
  <filter id="filter1508" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
   <feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="0.486771"/>
   <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="blur" operator="in" result="composite1"/>
   <feComposite in="composite1" in2="composite1" operator="in" result="composite2"/>
  </filter>
  <style>
   svg:hover g{
    filter: none;
   }
   svg:hover .path{
     fill: #fff;
   }
  </style>
 </defs>

  <g transform="matrix(10.503699,0,0,10.439736,-1021.468,-1393.9248)" filter="url(#filter1508)">
   <path class="path" d="m105.50465 157.28485 0.93914-1.32859-2.56638 0.0398 0.0236-2.05212 4.6573 4e-3c0.0987 2.2442-0.5579 3.57575-1.51689 4.60669z" fill="#518ef8"/>
   <path class="path" d="m101.32124 155.86132-1.759951 1.32292c2.432411 3.5455 5.380811 2.75653 7.480131 1.37039l-1.53677-1.26978c-1.81907 0.53171-3.40023 0.30489-4.18341-1.42353z" fill="#28b446"/>
   <path class="path" d="m101.25037 154.0305c-0.0984 0.58586-0.14247 1.1826 0.0709 1.83082l-1.759951 1.32292c-0.69101-1.47957-0.650834-2.97741-0.08268-4.48846z" fill="#fbbb00"/>
   <path class="path" d="m101.25037 154.0305c0.83252-1.71136 2.15985-1.9383 3.64983-1.67727l0.0709 0.22443c0.17648 0.079 0.3398 0.18096 0.63784 0.0472l1.45285-1.37016c-3.20771-1.70435-5.85383-1.60444-7.583122 1.44104z" fill="#f14336"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

stylus:

```
svg
  &:hover
    fill:#fff
```

или

```
svg path
  &:hover
    fill:#fff
```

можешь попробовать добавить !important

Answer (score 0):

В path, в параметре fill, надо указать цвет, который Вам надо.